# Link directly to google play app

Tags: android, google-play

We have an google play app and in it we have a link to download another game that we own.
When we press on the link, we get the 'Complete action using' android window.
How can we redirect directly to the store?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Linking to Your Products](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html). Most likely, you are using the website URL. Try the following intent below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.package.name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

You should also check if com.android.vending is installed before starting that intent.